# How to set pipeline variable for list of dictionaries and pass it to groovy

Tags: dictionary, arraylist, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have the below pipeline code:

```groovy
stage ("distribution"){
    steps{
        script{
            def rules = [
                [
                    "service_name": "core", 
                    "site_name": "*", 
                    "city_name": "*", 
                    "country_codes": ["*"]
                ]
            ]
            amd_distribution_distribute_bundle distribution_rules: rules
        }
    }
}
```

In the `amd_distribution_distribute_bundle.groovy` file I'm trying to print the value of it:

```
def call(Map parameters) {
    def DISTRIBUTION_RULES= parameters.distribution_rules
    sh '''
        echo ${DISTRIBUTION_RULES}
     '''
}
```

I'm getting in the console an empty string for it.
Do you any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using single quotes that do not interpolate `${DISTRIBUTION_RULES}` variable from the local variable. If you want to use it with `sh` step (execute as a shell script) you need to use double quotes to interpolate the value from the local variable.

```groovy
def call(Map parameters) {
    def DISTRIBUTION_RULES = parameters.distribution_rules
    sh """
        echo ${DISTRIBUTION_RULES}
    """
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to use single quotes but still access the `DISTRIBUTION_RULES` value, you would need to assign it to the environment variable. Keep in mind, however, that environment variable casts every value assigned to `String`. So if you try to assign a map to a env variable, you will get its string representation, not the real map. A shell script has access to all environment variables set in the pipeline.

```groovy
def call(Map parameters) {
    env.DISTRIBUTION_RULES = parameters.distribution_rules
    sh '''
        echo ${DISTRIBUTION_RULES}
    '''
}
```